# WPF decomposition - DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to move custom DataGrid column definition into a UserControl.

MyComboBoxColumn.xaml

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn 
    x:Class="WpfDecomposition.MyComboBoxColumn"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WpfToolkit"
    x:Name="_this"
    >

    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <Button Content="{Binding MyHeader, ElementName=_this}" ></Button>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

MyComboBoxColumn.cs

```
public partial class MyComboBoxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public MyComboBoxColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty MyHeaderProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyHeader", typeof(string), typeof(MyComboBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata("TEST"));
}
```

Main windows XAML:

```
<dg:DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:MyComboBoxColumn />
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

I would expect to see a button "TEST" in the column's header, but instead I see the empty button. Looks like the binding is broken. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because it can't find an element with the name `_this`. I get the following error in the Output window when I debug your code in Visual Studio:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot
>   find source for binding with reference
>   'ElementName=_this'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=MyHeader;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Button' (Name='TestButton'); target
>   property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

As for why it can't find it - I think that is because WPF bindings use the visual tree to find the source of the binding. In this case, the `MyComboBoxColumn` is not in the visual tree, so therefore it can't find an element with that name.

I also tried using `RelativeSource` to find the element, but that didn't work either - likely for the same reason.

The only thing that I could get to work is to set the `DataContext` of the button to the column itself in the constructor:

```
public MyComboBoxColumn()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.TestButton.DataContext = this;
}
```

And then change the binding in the XAML:

```
<tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=MyHeader}" x:Name="TestButton" />
</tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

That doesn't seem like the best way to do it, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or can't set the `DataContext` in the constructor (e.g. when creting columns dynamically in the code), set the column's `Header` property to the object you want to bind to (the data context) and then you can bind to this object in the `HeaderStyle` data template.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786773/how-to-set-the-datacontext-on-a-datagrid-column-header) for details.