# How to set the DataContext on a DataGrid Column Header

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, columnheader

In my **Silverlight 3** user control I am showing a basic **DataGrid** control. I need to **generate the columns programmatically** as follows:

```
Style headerStyle = (Style)Resources["ColumnHeaderStyle"];
DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
col.HeaderStyle = headerStyle;
dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

The style is defined as follows:

```
<Style x:Name="ColumnStyle" x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" 
       TargetType="prim:DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to **set the data context of the header to a "header" object** (with "Name" and "Data" properties which are referenced in the DataTemplate). Unfortunately, I cannot use the StackPanel_Loaded event as suggested [elsewhere](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/49089/312138.aspx), because the event handler is also called when the user starts a column drag&drop operation.

What is the correct way of setting the DataContext of a DataGrid column header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that one can use the **Header property** (which is of type Object) as the **DataContext for the DataTemplate** (set as shown above):

```
Style headerStyle = (Style)Resources["ColumnHeaderStyle"];
DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
col.HeaderStyle = headerStyle;
col.Header = myHeaderDataContext; // DataContext for ColumnHeaderStyle
dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: not quite the approach that I settled upon but +1 for explaining that the Header Property is the DataContext.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you would do it in XAML (this works in WPF; not sure if it works in SL)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Discount}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DiscountHeader}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, and it almost works.  When I databind *two* column header names, every column gets the name of the first column.  I have double and triple checked my databinding properties, and there aren't any silly mistakes, as far as I can tell.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: you are a life saver. Thanks a lot and this worked perfectly on .Net 4.5 wpf application.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Matt's answer, I came up with the solution of binding the header on the `DataGridCellsPanel` which in Snoop appeared to have the correct data context :

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CenterAlignedColumnHeaderStyle}">
         <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Location, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}}" />
      </Style>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

And this is non intrusive in the way that you can still inherits from custom styled headers (see exemple above) or event the base column header style:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
     <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Location, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}}" />
     </Style>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

This solution has the advantage of being pure and clean XAML and to refer to the closest ancestor holding the correct datacontext rather than trying to reach datacontext of top hierarchy elements like UserControl.

Comment: Thank you for nice solution! I took it as a basis for my [`solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding/22065842#22065842), all copyrights complied :).